# What are the eigenvalues of matrix $A$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $b \neq 0$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$

---

I know how to find the eigenvalues when all elements are given.
The way I find eigenvalues is by finding the characteristic polynomial, which comes out to be a quadratic equation in a $2\times2$ matrix, and solve that which gives the solutions.

Though, as values aren't given in this question, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: All elements are given: $A_{11}=A_{22}=a$, and $A_{21}=-A_{12}=b$. What more do you need?

Comment: @metamorphy Will be more mindful. Have done the same for now.

Comment: You need to write the eigenvalues in terms of $a$ and $b$

Comment: @Andrei So would the answer be a+bi and a-bi?

Comment: Yes. That's all.

Comment: @Andrei I'm a relatively new user; should I delete the question or answer my own question?

Comment: Just leave it as it is. Other people might find it useful. No need to answer your own question separately, sine anyone reading the comment would find the answer

Answer (score 2):

Let the eigenvalue be $\lambda$. Then

\begin{align*}
&\det(A - \lambda I) = 0\\
\implies&\begin{vmatrix}
a - \lambda & -b  \\
b & a - \lambda  \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0\\
\implies&(a - \lambda)^2 + b^2 = 0\\
\implies&\lambda^2 - 2a\lambda + a^2 + b^2 = 0
\end{align*}
Then we have that $$\lambda = \frac{2a \pm \sqrt{4a^2 - 4(a^2 + b^2)}}{2} = a \pm ib$$
Hence the eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1} = a + ib~$ and $~\lambda_{2} = a -ib.~$

Although the characteristic polynomial $~p(\lambda)$ will be reducible like this over a field $\mathbb{K}$, when $\mathbb{K}$ is **Algebraically Closed** (Like $\mathbb{C}$). So if the characteristic polynomial is defined over $\mathbb{R}$, then we have that
$$ (a - \lambda)^2 + b^2 = 0 \implies (a - \lambda) = 0 ~\text{ and }~ b = 0 $$

Comment: I cannot understand last part: if $b$ is supposed given, how can you put $b=0$? I would simply conclude that there are no eigenvalues in $\mathbb{R},$ unless $b=0$.

Comment: The last part is not related to the problem. Just mentioned that the reduction of polynomial $P(\lambda)$ is true over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{K}$(Like $\mathbb{C}$).  Nothing related to the problem. Just the factorization of the characteristic polynomial.